# What is the difference between Casper and Algorand?

Tags: casper

What is the difference between Casper and Algorand?

Casper -- Proof of Stake-Based Finality System overlaying an existing proof of work blockchain

Algorand -- Byzantine Consensus Based Protocol and?

Comment: Your question is a bit too broad, I think you should indicate on what point you would like the compare both. It seems that Algorand is a closed source consensus algorithm for instance https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/5tw9fd/how_does_casper_compare_to_algorand/

Answer (score 1):

One key difference is software patents. As Charles Hoskinson points out here: https://epicenter.tv/episode/234/

I think he provides a good "meta view" of mining algorithms with a comparison to their system, Ouroboros, in that video. Per my understanding of him, the bottom line is that there is still a great deal of research underway and likely to continue for quite a while. In all the different Proof of Work/Stake systems, there remains to be a great deal to be proven in terms of transactions per second and global consensus syncrhonization time metrics. We'll see if EOS can really produce blocks at 500mS -- particularly with the repeal of net neutrality. At the end of the day, that is all that will probably really matter to the community.

Comment: Does EOS claim that it can achieve blocks at 500ms?